# trying to get data out of the function throwing undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, variables, google-cloud-firestore, scoping

i am trying to store data fetched from firestore into variable  firebasecart but it throws undefined. please help me to get value fetched from firestore doc.data().cart for global usage.

```
    var firebasecart;
    console.log(firebascart); //throwing undefined

    function readData1(user){
    let db= firebase.firestore()
    return db.collection("users").doc(user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(function(doc) {
       if (doc.exists) {

           if (doc.data().cart.length > 0) {
               console.log(doc.data().cart);
               **firebasecart = doc.data().cart**
               console.log(storage.getCart())
           }
           else{
               console.log(doc.data().cart.length);
               console.log('true');
               console.log(doc.data().cart.length);
               }
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data().cart);
    
} else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
}
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
}
console.log(firebascart); //throwing undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I find your code hard to read. Although not the solution, using async/await instead of promise chaining might make it easier for you to isolate your problem.

```
const someFunction = async (req, res) => {
    const snapshot = await firebase.firestore()
       .collection("users")
       .doc(user.uid)
       .get()

    const data = snapshot.data()
    // Do stuff with data
    console.log(data.property)
}
```